# How to prevent keyboard from resizing Collection Views swift 3

Tags: swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller

As the title says, whenever i click on the search bar or any textfield really the keyboard appears and resizes the view. I have a collection view inside another collection view so i wouldnt mind if the collection view that resizes is the one inside, but its resizing the outside collection view. I have tried almost everything I can think of. So if anyone have any suggestion, I will greatly appreciated.

I already tried with supplementary views, uisearchcontroller... I dont know what else to do.. is like this has a listener that resizes the bottom constraint. This is the error method im getting, a bunch of times ( like 20 times everytime the keybarod appears)

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2016-09-27 22:27:04.726 APP[1446:734553] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2016-09-27 22:27:04.727 APP[1446:734553] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x14c6efa60>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x14d03d600; frame = (0 50; 414 622); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14c5a2a80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x14c5bdf40>; contentOffset: {414, 0}; contentSize: {1242, 622}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x14c6efa60>.
2016-09-27 22:27:04.727 APP[1446:734553] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```